# How I can bypass MySQL triger

Tags: php, mysql

I made a small website just for fun for file sharing, each account limited to 20 Files per day,
All members data stored inside MySQL table.
Username, Password, and Download number.
When someone click on download, a function will trigger and store +1 inside the table. and the downloading will begin.

I thought everything working great, after I saw the log file on my server, and I found someone who download a file without triggering the function and without leaving history Inside the database!

**How is that possible! and how I can do the same so I can block this bug!**

Here is the code:

```
    if (isset($_GET['download']) && !empty($_GET['download'])){

                if (!(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username']))){
                    echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, no username was specified in this download. Sorry for inconvenience.'; 
                    die;
                }

                $dl_username = $this->decrypt($_GET['username']);

                if (gator::getUser($dl_username) == false){
                    echo 'Only a member of this website can download this file. However, the username provided does not exist in the database. Sorry for inconvenience.';   
                    die;
                }

                $dl_user = gator::getUser($dl_username);
                if ($dl_user['downloads'] > 20){
                    echo 'Cannot download more files for today! You have crossed the limit of downloading 20 files.';
                    die;
                }
                gator::updateUser($dl_user['username'], array('downloads' => $dl_user['downloads'] + 1));

                $filename = $this->filterInput($this->decrypt($_GET['download']));

                if (in_array($filename, gatorconf::get('restricted_files'))) die;

                if (!file_exists($_SESSION['cwd'].DS.$filename)) die;

                // Set headers
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
// output file
            set_time_limit(0);
            $file = @fopen($_SESSION['cwd'].DS.$filename,"rb");
            while(!feof($file))
            {
                print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }

            gator::writeLog('download - '.$filename);
            echo 'Downloaded';


            die;
        }
```

**EDIT:** There is two log files, one for actions that record members actions on the website and the other one on my Apache server, that record everything and all connections even for non users.

And here is an example of how the file link look like: "no one can use hot links"

```
https://www.example.com/?download=MLB%20820-2186%20schematic%20diagram.pdf&username=Linda
```

Comment: Can those files be accessed directly via a URL?

Comment: Is it actually downloading files, or getting the data from the database?

Comment: @JeffUK Nope I blocked hot links, they can't do that.

Comment: @Barmar "Files" they can download files without triggering the function, it's pdf file stored in safe place on the server, no one can access it with direct link, encrypted too

Comment: How does the unauthorized download show up in the log file? Are you saying it's running this script, but the database isn't being updated?

Comment: There is two log files, one for actions, and the other one record everything, even nonmembers, He was authorized to download the file, but he bypass the trigger, There is no history inside the log file of actions,

Comment: Where's the code that sends the file?

Comment: I just updated my post @Phil